# VBA Excel: how to use a variable for the file number used for open, print and close

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to use a variable for the file number, instead of hard-coding it.

I have tried with conversions like CDbl to have a double, as it seems that #1 means convert 1 into double.. But this did not work.
It also does not work without conversion, so until now, using #1 (or any number) is the only way to interact with a file that worked fine.

```vb
Open f_output For Append As #2
Print #2, "hello"
Close #2
```

I would like it to look like

```vb
dim fileNumber as double
fileNumber = 2
Open f_output For Append As fileNumber
Print fileNumber, "hello"
Close fileNumber
```

Comment: See the [`Open` statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/open-statement) docs, and you can use [`FreeFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/freefile-function) to get the next available number. See the example under the freefile docs - you need the `#` before the variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the answer I was looking for.

```
dim fileNum
fileNum = 3

Open f_output For Append As #fileNum
Print #fileNum, s
Close #fileNum
```

Additionally, the built-in function FreeFile can be used to get a free file number.

```
fileNum = FreeFile
```